# Iterate lists of different length using Java 8 streams

Tags: java-8, java-stream

I am trying to iterate over three lists of different size but not getting the exact logic of how i can retrieve data from them and store in another list.
I was able to handle up to two list until I add some more filtration  to the elements. For now I am using 3 for loops but i want to use Java 8 streams if possible. Can someone please suggest me the correct logic for the below iterations.

```
public class CustomDto {

public static void main(String... args) {

    List<String> list1 = Arrays.asList("Hello", "World!");
    List<String> list2 = Arrays.asList("Hi", "there");
    List<String> list3 = Arrays.asList("Help Me");
    Map<Integer, Object> map = new HashMap<>();

    for (int i = 0; i < list1.size(); i++) {
        List<String> list4 = new LinkedList();
        for (int j = 0; j < list2.size(); j++) {

            for (int k = 0; k < list3.size(); k++) {

                if (!(list2.get(j).equals(list3.get(k))))
                    list4.add(list2.get(j));
            }

            if (j > list4.size() - 1) {
                list4.add(null);
            }
        }
        map.put(i, list4);
    }
}
```

}

All i want to convert the above code into stream, in which i can iterate a list inside another list and can use the index of one another.

Comment: what is `list` and `uniqueCombinationsList`?  this is really unclear at this point

Comment: Edited the code again please have a look.

Comment: how about you remove all the irrelevant code and present us a much simpler example?

Comment: @Eugene Is it fine  now?

Comment: to me, no. we still don't know what `list2` is, can you make the same example using some Lists that contain some strings for example? Something we could easily verify in our IDE\s for example?

Comment: @Eugene, I have modified the complete code and now this can be used as is into another Java IDE

Comment: You aren't telling us **what** you're trying to do. I see you have a triple-nested loop. What are you trying to find? What is so special about `list4`? I mean, what exact elements is it supposed to contain? Please describe what you are trying to achieve and what exact problem you're facing.

Comment: @Federico Peralta Schaffner I have added the comments.

Comment: I have modified the complete problem statement for peoples to understand.

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void main(String... args) {
    List<String> list1 = Arrays.asList("Hello", "World!");
    List<String> list2 = Arrays.asList("Hi", "there");
    List<String> list3 = Arrays.asList("Help Me");

    List<String> list4 = concat(list1, list2, list3); //you can add as many lists as you like here
    System.out.println(list4);
}

private static List<String> concat(List<String>... lists) {
    return Stream.of(lists)
            .flatMap(List::stream)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

**Output**

```
[Hello, World!, Hi, there, Help Me]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this create a multiple dimension array out of List, from there you can use stream too

```
Customdto[][] listArray = new Customdto[][]{  l1.toArray(new Customdto[]{})
        ,  l2.toArray(new Customdto[]{}),  l3.toArray(new Customdto[]{})};
    int size = listArray[0].length > listArray[1].length && listArray[0].length > listArray[2].length ?listArray[0].length
            :(listArray[1].length > listArray[2].length ? listArray[1].length:listArray[2].length);
    for(int i = 0; i <size;i++)
    {
        if(listArray[0].length >i && listArray[1].length >i && listArray[2].length >i &&
                listArray[0][i].equals(listArray[1][i]) 
                && listArray[1][i].getCalendarDate().equals(listArray[2][i].getCalendarDate()))
        {
            l4.add(listArray[1][i]);
        }else
        {
            l4.add(null);
        }
    }
```

Tried with Below Input

```
List<Customdto> l1 = new ArrayList<Customdto>();
        List<Customdto> l2 = new ArrayList<Customdto>();
        List<Customdto> l3 = new ArrayList<Customdto>();
        List<Customdto> l4 = new ArrayList<Customdto>();
        l1.add(new Customdto(1));
        l1.add(new Customdto(2));
        l1.add(new Customdto(3));
        l1.add(new Customdto(4));
        l2.add(new Customdto(1));
        l2.add(new Customdto(2));
        l2.add(new Customdto(3));
        l3.add(new Customdto(1));
        l3.add(new Customdto(2));
```

Output is

```
[Customdto [id=1], Customdto [id=2], null, null]
```

Comment: Thanks for your efforts @Nishant, But i have modified the code again  , also I am expecting to use streams here, and trying not to use any loops if possible.

Comment: From your new program I am not clear what you want to achieve @Vinay. Can you explain a bit more

Comment: I want to iterate 3 lists using streams and collect all the data including null values in list4

Comment: Tested your code and it just out list 2 times in map.{0=[Hi, there], 1=[Hi, there]}. I am still not clear what you want to do with your list